# Is it possible to find a closed form using modular arithmetic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, closed-form

Look at this sequence:

> $$a_n=\left\{1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, \cdots \right\}$$

This is a periodic sequence. Repeating block is $\left\{1, 0, 0, 2\right\}.$

Here is my closed form:

> $$a_n = \frac 14((-1)^n + (2 + i) (-i)^n + (2 - i) i^n + 3)$$
>
> where, $i^2=-1$

Is it possible to find a closed form using modular arithmetic?

I mean for example,

$A\mod 3+B\mod 4 \cdots \cdots \cdots$

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a function of $n$ that behaves as follows:

$f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } n \mod 4 = 1\\ 0 \text{ if } n \mod 4 = 2,3\\ 2 \text{ if } n \mod 4 = 0\end{cases}$

Let's denote $n \mod 4$ by $n'$. The polynomial $n'(n'-2)(n'-3)$ is $0$ when $n'=0,2,3$ and takes the value $2$ when $n'=1$. So this suggests

$\frac 1 2 n'(n'-2)(n'-3)$

should be part of a closed form expression. Similarly $(n'-1)(n'-2)(n'-3)$ is $0$ when $n'=1,2,3$ and takes the value $-6$ when $n'=0$. So this suggests

$-\frac 1 3 (n'-1)(n'-2)(n'-3)$

should be part of the expression too. So we have

$f(n) = \frac 1 2 n'(n'-2)(n'-3) - \frac 1 3 (n'-1)(n'-2)(n'-3)\\
= \frac 1 6 (n'+2)(n'-2)(n'-3) \\
= \frac 1 6 (n'^3 -3n'^2 -4n'+12) \text{ where } n'=n\mod 4$

Comment: That polynomial is the one interpolating $(1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(4,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using modular-arithmetic is quite similar to using floor functions so you can also use that instead. Here is a possible solution:
$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{6}\left((n-4\lfloor n/4\rfloor)^3 -3(n-4\lfloor n/4\rfloor)^2 - 4(n-\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + 12 \right)
$$
In this case $n-4\lfloor n/4 \rfloor$ would be the same as $n\pmod 4$.